# Export BIG mysql table to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql table with 2.8 million records and i want to convert all of these to JSON. I wrote a script to convert but it stops with a memory warning.

Then i tried to create smaller files (file1 is 0,
 to 100000 records, file 2 is 100000 to 1000000 records etc ) and combine with windows copy command. It works, but each file is a JSON array (like [{...}]) and when it merges, it becomes separate sections like [{}][{}] (where i want it like [{................}])

Is there any better solution to do this ?

Comment: can't you just delete the unneeded braces when you copy them together ?

Comment: Why not convert each record to JSON individually and write them to a file one record at a time? If you fetch the table in 'batches' it will be quite quick. The memory usage will be minimal. Depending of the size of the rows, assuming 300 bytes per row, the output file will be about 1GB (gigabyte).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change 'memory_limit' in your php.ini configuration. Also if this takes much time then you can handle this by cron job(if possible)

OR

you can decode your ALL json files and merge it in a single array and then again encode in json and put in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did this. Please see the steps (i am not sure this is the right one, but it works).

Totally, i have 2.6 million records in my table. I created a script which will select mysql rows, convert to json and write to a file.

Select records from 0 to 1 million and create file 1. Repeat from 1 to 2 million and 2 to 2.6 million for file2 and file 3.

Combine these files using JQ (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and create a single JSON file.